# How to I control the z-index of a GroundOverlay versus map features

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using the android google maps API V2 and I would like to draw a GroundOverlay on top of the map features (for example, the street names, names of towns, parks, e.t.c.).  Right now, my GroundOverlay works great but if my overlay happens to have a street name written on it, it becomes unreadable because Google Maps also chooses to draw a street name over top of everything, thereby partially obscuring my overlay.

Can I overload some function of GroundOverlay or somehow cause it it be drawn last, on top of everything else on the map?

Changing the z-index of the GroundOverlay does not solve this issue, because the GroundOverlay z-index is relative to other GroundOverlays, not relative to other map features.

Comment: Could you post some code of what you've tried, please?

Comment: This can be observed in almost any GroundOverlay code, even the mapdemo code from google.  If you zoom into the "Newark" overlay, you see the street names on top of image.

Comment: If you have the android SDK source code with google play services sample code, see the following file:

sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/samples/maps/src/com/example/mapdemo/GroundOverlayDemoActivity.java

Answer (score 1):

You cannot force GroundOverlay above map features.

You can only use satellite mode (or without map tiles), where street names and other thingies are not drawn at all.

I'd suggest issuing a feature request for flag to disable them in normal/terrain maps on [gmaps-api-issues](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=apitype%3DAndroid2).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot place GroundOverlays or TileOverlays on top of labels. Your best option might be to use a different map type. You're probably using the default `MAP_TYPE_NORMAL`. This can be changed after the map has been created (i.e. in the `onMapReady` method by using the [`mMap.setMapType(...)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#public-final-void-setmaptype-int-type) method). Here are some possibilities:

### Map Types Without Labels

`MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE` and `MAP_TYPE_NONE` don't include labels. If you don't need **any** map data outside of your GroundOverlay, using `MAP_TYPE_NONE` will save on mobile data.

### `MAP_TYPE_NORMAL` + Custom Map Style

You can easily create your own map styles by using the [Styling Wizard](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/). It allows you to create a style that excludes labels entirely (among other things). Once you've created a style you like, you can copy the JSON code generated by that website and add it to the project file `res/raw/style_json.json`. The style can then be applied like this:

```
mMap.setMapType( GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL );

try
{
    boolean success = mMap.setMapStyle(
            MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
                    getContext(), R.raw.style_json ) );

    if( !success )
    {
        Log.e( TAG, "Style parsing failed." );
    }
}
catch( Resources.NotFoundException e )
{
    Log.e( TAG, "Can't find style. Error: ", e );
}
```

### `MAP_TYPE_NONE` + Custom Map Tiles

If you **need** to have labels outside of your GroundOverlay, you could add a TileOverlay of non-Google map tiles (like those provided by [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/about)). These typically include the labels within the map tiles themselves. So if your GroundOverlay is added with a higher [z-index](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/shapes#z-index), it will appear on top of these other map tiles!